# Потоки и IntentService

Tags: android, android-service, android-threads

В каком потоке происходит работа `IntentService`? Вроде как по определению это подкласс обычного `Service`, у которого метод `onHandleIntent` отрабатывает в background потоке:

> Clients send requests through Context.startService(Intent) calls; the
>   service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a
>   worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.

...

> All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as
>   long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop),
>   but only one request will be processed at a time.

Но правильно ли я понимаю, что всё равно сам `IntentService` работает в главном (UI) потоке, и из него уже запускает новый worker/background-поток? И при завершении приложения `IntentService` будет убит вместе со всем приложением, до конца выполнится только текущий метод `onHandleIntent`, но следующий уже не будет запущен?

К примеру, если в активити есть следующий код:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyIntentService.class);
   this.startService(intent);
}
```

и приложение завершается, когда весь цикл выполнен, но метод `onHandleIntent` отработал только один раз, то больше метод `onHandleIntent` вызван не будет?

**UPD**

Например, если говорить об исходном коде класса `IntentService`:

```
public abstract class IntentService extends Service {
   ...
   @Override
    public void onStart(@Nullable Intent intent, int startId) {
        Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.arg1 = startId;
        msg.obj = intent;
        mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        onStart(intent, startId);
        return mRedelivery ? START_REDELIVER_INTENT : START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
    ...
    @WorkerThread
    protected abstract void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent);
}
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что в этом случае (в примере с циклом) метод `onStartCommand` выполнится 5 раз, и вызовет 5 раз метод `onStart`, который с помощью mServiceHandler помещает intent-ы в очередь, но при завершении main-потока умирает вместе с ним?..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> В каком потоке происходит работа IntentService?

работа IntentService происходит в отдельном Thread, который создается во время создания сервиса, все остальные Message будут поститься на Looper от этого треда, те получается что это SingleQueue.

> Но правильно ли я понимаю, что всё равно сам IntentService работает в
>   главном (UI)?

Не совсем точно. По умолчанию все компоненты одного приложения работают в одном процессе, но вам никто не помешает запустить сервис из другого потока, внутри себя он создаст поток из контекста который вы передадите. Как только процесс завершится поток сервиса умрет.

> И при завершении приложения IntentService будет убит вместе со всем
>   приложением, до конца выполнится только текущий метод onHandleIntent,
>   но следующий уже не будет запущен?

Да. Но подмечу если компоненты одного приложения работают в одном процессе.

> и приложение завершается, когда весь цикл выполнен, но метод
>   onHandleIntent отработал только один раз, то больше метод
>   onHandleIntent вызван не будет?

не факт, здесь работа разных потоков может успеть вызываться, а может нет. Смотря как быстро вы убиваете процесс. Смею предположить если сделать, что-то типо `System.exit(0)` то не успеет даже 1-раз вызваться.

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что в этом случае (в примере с циклом) метод
>   onStartCommand выполнится 5 раз, и вызовет 5 раз метод onStart,
>   который с помощью mServiceHandler помещает intent-ы в очередь, но при
>   завершении main-потока умирает вместе с ним?.

Да.

Comment: Спасибо за такой развёрнутый ответ! :)

Answer (score 1):

И я решила ещё проверить на практике свои предположения, для этого создала класс, аналогичный IntentService, добавив в методы этого класса только логирование, и добавила логирование в цикл:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Cycle: " + i);
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestService.class);
      startService(intent);
}
```

В результате получила следующий вывод:

```
Cycle: 0
Cycle: 1
Cycle: 2
Cycle: 3
Cycle: 4
IntentServiceWithLog onStartCommand
IntentServiceWithLog onStart
TestService onHandleIntent
IntentServiceWithLog onStartCommand
IntentServiceWithLog onStart
IntentServiceWithLog onStartCommand
IntentServiceWithLog onStart
TestService onHandleIntent
IntentServiceWithLog onStartCommand
IntentServiceWithLog onStart
IntentServiceWithLog onStartCommand
IntentServiceWithLog onStart
TestService onHandleIntent
TestService onHandleIntent
TestService onHandleIntent
```

И если ещё добавить в эти методы логирование имени потока:

```
Log.i("THREAD", Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

гипотеза тоже подтверждается:

```
IntentServiceWithLog onStartCommand
THREAD: main
IntentServiceWithLog onStart
THREAD: main
TestService onHandleIntent
THREAD: IntentService[TestService]
```